# CSS text difference Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, primefaces

The menu appears different between chrome/firefox

You can see the difference in this screen :  http://postimg.org/image/wvg194dtv/

I'm using primefaces 3, JSF 2 firefox 24.0 Chrome Version 30.0.1599.69 m

< p : layoutUnit style=" font-size: 12px;font-family: Verdana" position="west" size="220" >

...

```
< p : menu  style="width:200px;font-size: 12px;"   >
```

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Use a css reset

see this for more information:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899792/font-size-issues-comparing-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: You should post minimal HTML and CSS code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

YUI 2: Reset CSS
The foundational YUI Reset CSS file removes and neutralizes the inconsistent default styling of HTML elements, creating a level playing field across A-grade browsers and providing a sound foundation upon which you can explicitly declare your intentions.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/