# Same content with different font-size results in wrong alignment

Tags: html, css

I have exactly (I changed the values via Developer tools in Chrome) the same content rendered with `font-size` (unit `em`):

- `1.0`

[image: 1.0]

- `1.1`

[image: 1.1]

- `1.2`

[image: 1.2]

- `1.3`

[image: 1.3]

- `1.4`

[image: 1.4]

But as you can see with `1.2` the alignment of the two blocks is different in Chrome (also in Firefox). You can see it in action [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5cKK.png) and [here](http://blog.cincura.net/233484-how-slow-the-lock-statement-actually-is/).

How is that possible?

Comment: They appear to be completely different font-sizes for me in both chrome and firefox, as chrome has a default of 16px for that element and 12px in firefox.

Comment: Checkout this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899792/font-size-issues-comparing-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: But I'm not comparing Chrome and Firefox. All screenshots are taken form Chrome. I'm just saying that the `1.2em` weird behavior happens in Chrome and also in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly the `font-size: 80%` definition for `body` was causing this. I removed it and recomputed all the rest and it's fine now.