# CSS centered position in Div differs in FF/Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, position, centering

I have a span which is centered horizontally and vertically in its parent with the following CSS:

```css
.cal-day {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar-button">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
    <span class="cal-day">21</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

(.icon-calendar is an icomoon-font, position is relative to make the parent div create space)

This works in Chrome and Safari. in Firefox, the container is a few pixels off to the top (I attached an image).

I guess, it's the font that is being rendered different in FF/Chrome... But how can I make them render it equally?

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899792/font-size-issues-comparing-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: did you try to add  `-moz-transform` for FF?

Comment: yes, I did... same result

Comment: @Sahil: not working