# span height different in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: html, css

The following element:

```
<span>Test</span>

span {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
```

Has a height of 19px in Chrome, and 21px in Firefox ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ay5c3nh/13/)). I tried applying all sorts of CSS resets/normalization, the height is still different. The text itself is rendered identically, but the element height is off by 2 pixels, which breaks my layout.

Any way to fix it without using (inline) block elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
span {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.15;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The difference is due to different render of fonts in browsers.

Comment: Yeah block elements work fine, but it has some side effects. Why isn't inline working?

Comment: @riv the difference is due to different render of fonts in browsers. you should set **height** or **line-height** ;

Comment: Inline element can't accept height and it depend on font rendering

Comment: Oh my bad, it seems that line-height on inline elements affects the *parent* block element height instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known problem. It is caused by the fact that Firefox and Chrome use different rendering engines, Gecko and Webkit respectively.
Unfortunately there is no 'best' way to fix it.

You can find a few workarounds in [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14324/font-displays-differently-in-firefox-vs-chrome) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899792/font-size-issues-comparing-chrome-and-firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Because of `span` is inline element, you should re-write your code like following way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(el => {
  el.textContent = el.offsetHeight + "px";
});
```

```css
span {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.15;
  display: inline-block; /* Key line */
  vertical-align: top; /* It is recommended when using "display: inline-block"*/
}
```

```html
<span>Test</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for that behaviour is that you are using a `span` which is an inline element. It does not change its container height based on the line height but based on its parent block element. Apparently, Chrome and Firefox have different default styles for that.

Either make the `span` a block element using `display: block` or replace it with a block element like `div`.

Answer (score -2):

About the height differences the issue is that you have added font-size, family and line-height as well.

So because of this 3 things :

```
font-family: Verdana;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1.15;
```

your size of text getting bigger then 16px.