# display text only in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

i know that

```
<!--[if !IE]>--> 
TEXT
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

will not display TEXT in IE. But i need this to display **only** in Chrome. How can i do that?

Comment: Conditional comments exist only in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using CSS, like answered [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292258/chrome-conditional-comments)

Answer (score 1):

Get a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and check if the browser is Google Chrome.

The following question's answer contains a code example: [Distinguish Chrome from Safari using jQuery.browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303858/distinguish-chrome-from-safari-using-jquery-browser)

**Or** you could check out [this blog post](http://davidwalsh.name/detecting-google-chrome-javascript), which does the same but without a framework.

Comment: can't i do this in bare html?

Comment: @Stals: Not that I currently know off.