# Letter spacing issue with 'overlapping' character

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, letter-spacing

I'm having some trouble with a font I found on [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Marck+Script).

As you can see in the image posted below, the capital V in 'Versus' overlaps with the 'e' when i'm using Firefox. Though when i'm using Chrome (or IE) it does not overlap and leaves me with an ugly space between the two characters.

Is there any way to fix this and make it look like the one in Firefox? Or should I start looking for another font?

[image: Chrome/IE & Firefox Comparison]

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Versus</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Versus</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
font-size: 100px;
color:#444;
text-align:center;
padding:0 50px;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #777;
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you making your users download the font when they come to your site? If that is the case, then it is usually frowned upon. I will post an answer if you want to venture down this path.

Comment: This is called a "kerning glitch". It's probably the version of the font being used.

Comment: Agree with @Ekaterina.  When making a web-site, avoid using fonts that visitors/clients are unlikely to have installed.  And always provide one of the defaults (serif, sans-serif, monospace, ...) in your css's font-family list.

Comment: Ekaterina, I supply my visitors with the font using google webfonts. I've added my code for some extra clarification. Is this recommended?

Comment: I posted an answer. Standard web protocol is to not use a font that needs to be downloaded, but in the end it's your site and you can do with it as you please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix the spacing in a font you should use:

```
letter-spacing: 10px /* How ever much you need */
```

Without knowing the specifics on the HTML and the CSS you already have in place, you can fix the problem area by using something like this:

style

```
span { letter-spacing: -4px }
```

html

```
<span>V</span>ersus
```

It's hokie, but it should work.

Comment: The fix makes things worse on Firefox

Comment: Of course because it was a fix for Chrome and IE. You will need to put your style in comment tags <!--[if IE]>. I don't know the one for Chrome. Here is a post about conditional styles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292258/chrome-conditional-comments

Answer (score 1):

Firefox nowadays supports kerning when using a font with kerning pairs. Other browsers haven’t caught up. There are several proposed CSS features that would affect kerning, and Firefox has some support to them, but the other browsers don’t.

So you should look for another font. Manually tuning spacing by `letter-spacing` or `margin` properties is troublesome and risky; you easily end up with breaking things on Firefox.

If you keep using the Marck Script font, it is better to download it and install it on your server and use it from there. There are problems with many Google fonts when used on the Google server. In this case, IE 9 in Standards Mode does not use the font; the error code CSS3117 appears in the console, so there is apparently something wrong in Google settings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this clarifies a lot!