# Can conditional comments work for borwsers other than just IE?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I am wanting to use a separate CSS sheet on my web-page for Chrome & Safari, than the one used for all other borwser types. I have previously used conditional comments when doing this for IE, such as:

```
<!--[if !IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"><![endif]-->
```

but I am wanting the above to work for Chrome & Safari instead. Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps you should look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621749/how-do-i-detect-the-users-browser-and-apply-a-specific-css-file

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/1292258/662581

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments only work in IE.

This is a creative way to address this problem. I learned it from [here](http://phrappe.com/css/conditional-css-for-webkit-based-browsers/)

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {  
  /* CSS Statements that only apply on webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has a vendor specific one as well.

```
@media screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   /* Firefox browser based CSS goes here */
}
```